# Agrupar listas por un indice

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Tengo una lista de datos extraida desde sqlalchemy que están organizados nombre, dia de la semana, temperatura inicial, temperatura final. Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es iterar y agrupar esas listas.

Así tengo más o menos el código pero no me funciona:

```
datos = [['ANGELICA', 'Lunes', '35.6', '36.5'], ['ANYELA', 'Lunes', '35.6', '36.5'], ['ANYI', 'Lunes', '35.6', '36.6'], ['ANGELICA', 'Martes', '35.6', '36.5'], ['ANYELA', 'Martes', '35.6', '36.5'], ['ANYI', 'Martes', '35.6', '36.6'], ['ANGELICA', 'Miercoles', '35.6', '36.5'], ['ANYELA', 'Miercoles', '35.6', '36.5'], ['ANYI', 'Miercoles', '35.6', '36.6'], ['ANGELICA', 'Jueves', '35.6', '36.5'], ['ANYELA', 'Jueves', '35.6', '36.5'], ['ANYI', 'Jueves', '35.6', '36.6'], ['ANGELICA', 'Viernes', '35.6', '36.5'], ['ANYELA', 'Viernes', '35.6', '36.5'], ['ANYI', 'Viernes', '35.6', '36.6']]
for t in datos:
        if t.completion_date >= str(inicio) and t.completion_date <= str(fin): # Realiza un filtrado por fecha
            colabor = [t.full_name, t.days, t.entry_temperature, t.outlet_temperature]
            user.append(colabor)
    print(user)
```

el resultado que busco es el siguiente:

```
datos = [['ANGELICA', ['Lunes', '35.6', '36.5'], ['Martes', '35.6', '36.5'], ['Miercoles', '35.6', '36.5'],['Jueves', '35.6', '36.5'],['Viernes', '35.6', '36.5']],
        ['ANYELA', ['Lunes', '35.6', '36.5'], ['Martes', '35.6', '36.5'],['Miercoles', '35.6', '36.5'],['Jueves', '35.6', '36.5'],['Viernes', '35.6', '36.5']], 
        ['ANYI', ['Lunes', '35.6', '36.6'], ['Martes', '35.6', '36.6'], ['Miercoles', '35.6', '36.6'],['Jueves', '35.6', '36.6'],['Viernes', '35.6', '36.6']]]
```

Mi idea es poder agruparle a cada usuario su respectivo día con la temperatura de ingreso y salida en una sola lista.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los datos son una lista, donde cada item es [Nombre, Día, Temp1, Temp2].

La forma estándar de agrupar por un concepto (Nombre en este caso), es crear un diccionario y usar Nombre como llave y su valor será una lista de items [Dia, Temp1, Temp2].

Entonces, recorremos la lista. De cada muestra sacamos el Nombre (`muestra[0]`), que usamos como llave en el diccionario. El valor retornado es una lista, a la cual agregamos el resto de la muestra (`muestra[1:]`)

Para acortar la historia, usamos `defaultdict`, que es igual a un diccionario normal, excepto que si pides una llave que no existe, la crea. Cuando creas el diccionario:

```
resumen = defaultdict(list)
```

tienes que pasarle un *callable* como argumento. En este caso, `list` para que cree una lista vacía.

**Código**

```
from collections import defaultdict

datos = [['ANGELICA', 'Lunes', '35.6', '36.5'], ['ANYELA', 'Lunes', '35.6', '36.5'], ['ANYI', 'Lunes', '35.6', '36.6'], ['ANGELICA', 'Martes', '35.6', '36.5'], ['ANYELA', 'Martes', '35.6', '36.5'], ['ANYI', 'Martes', '35.6', '36.6'], ['ANGELICA', 'Miercoles', '35.6', '36.5'], ['ANYELA', 'Miercoles', '35.6', '36.5'], ['ANYI', 'Miercoles', '35.6', '36.6'], ['ANGELICA', 'Jueves', '35.6', '36.5'], ['ANYELA', 'Jueves', '35.6', '36.5'], ['ANYI', 'Jueves', '35.6', '36.6'], ['ANGELICA', 'Viernes', '35.6', '36.5'], ['ANYELA', 'Viernes', '35.6', '36.5'], ['ANYI', 'Viernes', '35.6', '36.6']]

resumen = defaultdict(list)
for muestra in datos:
    resumen[muestra[0]].append(muestra[1:])

for k, v in resumen.items():
    print(k, v)
```

produce

```
ANGELICA [['Lunes', '35.6', '36.5'], ['Martes', '35.6', '36.5'], ['Miercoles', '35.6', '36.5'], ['Jueves', '35.6', '36.5'], ['Viernes', '35.6', '36.5']]
ANYELA [['Lunes', '35.6', '36.5'], ['Martes', '35.6', '36.5'], ['Miercoles', '35.6', '36.5'], ['Jueves', '35.6', '36.5'], ['Viernes', '35.6', '36.5']]
ANYI [['Lunes', '35.6', '36.6'], ['Martes', '35.6', '36.6'], ['Miercoles', '35.6', '36.6'], ['Jueves', '35.6', '36.6'], ['Viernes', '35.6', '36.6']]
```